# Term for "utilize for commercialization"

Tags: word-choice

I'm making a résumé right now and I need a term for **"utilize for commercialization"** as in:

> I have learned how to *[use for commercialization]* the concepts learned in school.

Or something like that. I came up with this wild idea of:

> I have learned how to *weaponize* the knowledge learned in Economics class.

But that sounds too hostile or so.

Help me get hired! :)

Comment: How about **monetize**? People are always talking about how to make money giving stuff away for free on the Net.

Comment: That seems correct, but I think it's too direct. Haha. I need something fancier and one that's a beat-around-the-bush, sorry.

Comment: Rather than use ugly and essentially misleading euphemisms, why not say something a little more **honest**, eg, _I have learned **how to apply in the marketplace** what I learned in Economics classes._ If you say this or anything else, of course, you'll have to back it up by giving at least one example of how you turned the law of supply & demand into cold, hard cash. Business people don't use BS when talking to each other about their raison d'être (lucre, "filthy" & otherwise), they just use BS when talking to the rest of us. In any case, this is softer & less direct.

Comment: *Commercialize* is itself a good option; *bring to market* is fine as well. Sounds cliched but '*scale up*' works.

Comment: At least in British English, you don't "make" a résumé, you write one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question and the cited example, it appears that you are looking for words like **implement**, **execute**, **apply**. They look fine on a resume.

For example:

> ...learned to *(creatively) execute* the skills gained in Economics class.
>
> ...learned to *(resourcefully) apply* the knowledge gathered in economics class.

Don't use weaponize, sounds like you will bring down the building. ;)

Comment: Thank you. Haha. Those words seem so obvious, I wonder how I haven't thought of them. :P

Comment: Glad I could help. Cheers!!